# How to set property -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="E:\trust.jks" for testng?

Tags: ant, testng, java-opts

I am running testng file using ANT and I want to set the property -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="E:\trust.jks".

Comment: I am trying to login through code on RSA Authentication Manager but I am getting following error

Comment: Test Connection failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Post the Ant code that runs testng.

Comment: @NikhilRChaudhari, you should able to provide in the command line like `ant -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="E:\trust.jks"`

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/v1SK8zxRwM8

Comment: above suggestion worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <test name="Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[ System.setProperty("username","TestNG");return true;]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="organized.chaos.testng.FunnyTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

this solution worked for me. specifying in suite. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/v1SK8zxRwM8